# How to get response in AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am stuck during implementation of an application.

I have a JSP page where I am showing all user details in a table format. Each row in that table is having a check box. User should be able to remove selected row/rows. There are 3 buttons, `ADD`, `REMOVE` and `UPDATE`. When I will click add button, one dialogue box will appear which will contain a form and it will take the user details. After clicking the save button on that dialogue box, one row will be added to that table with all those details.

I have already implemented above use-case. But I am facing one issue.
Currently check box value is the employeeId. When I am adding an employee, I am doing a ajax call which is calling a controller followed by service and DAO. In DAO layer I am getting the newly generated EMP id(generating through sequence). I can pass that ID to controller class. But how can I get it back to the JSP so that I can set it to the value of newly added checkbox ?

**Ajax Call :**

```
$("#addEmpBtn").click(function () {
          var empData = $("#empForm").serialize();
          $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "manageEmpMain/addEmp.do",
                data: empData
               });  
          $('#dialogEmp').dialog('close');
          $('#empTable').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="empCheck" id="empCheck"></td><td>Other details</td></tr>');
      });
```

I want the id as value of above mentioned checkbox

**Controller :**

```
public class ManageEmpMainController extends MultiActionController {

ManageEmpService manageEmpService;

    public ModelAndView addEmp(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        Employee emp = new Employee(\\Details);
        manageEmpService.addEmp(emp);

        return null;
    }
}
```

**DAO :**

```
public class ManageEmployeeDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport {
@Override
    public void addEmployee(Employee emp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int empId = (Integer)getHibernateTemplate().save(emp);
        System.out.println("ID " +empId); // This empId can be passed to the controller. Not implemented yet 

    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 0):

AJax calls are asynchronous. That means your other code might execute before you get response from ajax call. and thats what happening in your code. Moreover you are not using any returned value from server.

use this :

```js
$("#addEmpBtn").click(function () {
  var empData = $("#empForm").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url  : "manageEmpMain/addEmp.do",
    data: empData
  }).done(function(response){
    $('#dialogEmp').dialog('close');
    $('#empTable').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="" name="empCheck" id="' + (response.id) + '"></td><td>Other details</td></tr>');
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But not getting how its going to help. Its doing the same thing right ?

Comment: not doing the same thing my friend.. check my updated answer

Comment: `done` or better `success` will be called after ajax

Comment: Ok but how can i get that value in done method ? I can get that id till controller level. After that how can i pass it to the JSP as I am not returning any Model from controller?